# LINQ EF Join with added CROSS JOIN

Tags: linq, entity-framework, join

This linq to ef syntax produces the sql syntax shown below.  How can I get it to produce without the CROSS JOIN?  The cross join is giving me a ton of extra records.

```
vehicleList = (from _vehicle in shireyContext.Vehicles
                                   join _statusDescription in shireyContext.StatusDescriptions
                                   on _vehicle.Status equals _statusDescription.StatusId
                                   join _newOptions2 in shireyContext.VehicleOption_New
                                   on _vehicle.StockNo equals _newOptions2.StockNo
                                   where _vehicle.NewOrUsed == NewOrUsed && _vehicle.Model == Model && _newOptions2.Color != null                                       
                                   from _newOptions in shireyContext.VehicleOption_New
                                   select new VehicleDomainEntity
                                   {
                                       StockNo = _vehicle.StockNo,
                                       Year = _vehicle.VehicleYear,
                                       Make = _vehicle.Make,
                                       Model = _vehicle.Model,
                                       Description = _newOptions2.Description,
                                       ExteriorColor = _vehicle.ExteriorColor,
                                       InteriorColor = _vehicle.InteriorColor,
                                       InternetPrice = _vehicle.CodedCost,
                                       ListPrice = _vehicle.ListPrice,
                                       Status = _statusDescription.StatusDescriptionText,
                                       NewOrUsed = _vehicle.NewOrUsed,
                                       Mileage = _vehicle.Mileage,
                                       VIN = _vehicle.VIN
                                   }).ToList();
```

**produces this sql:**

```
 SELECT
Extent2.StatusId AS StatusId,
Extent1.StockNo AS StockNo,
Extent1.VehicleYear AS VehicleYear,
Extent1.Make AS Make,
Extent1.Model AS Model,
Extent3.Description AS Description,
Extent1.ExteriorColor AS ExteriorColor,
Extent1.InteriorColor AS InteriorColor,
Extent1.CodedCost AS CodedCost,
Extent1.ListPrice AS ListPrice,
Extent2.StatusDescriptionText AS StatusDescriptionText,
Extent1.NewOrUsed AS NewOrUsed,
Extent1.Mileage AS Mileage,
Extent1.VIN AS VIN
FROM  dbo.Vehicles AS Extent1
INNER JOIN dbo.StatusDescription AS Extent2 ON Extent1.Status = Extent2.StatusId
INNER JOIN dbo.VehicleOption_New AS Extent3 ON Extent1.StockNo = Extent3.StockNo
CROSS JOIN dbo.VehicleOption_New AS Extent4
WHERE (Extent1.NewOrUsed = 'N') AND (Extent1.Model = 'cts' AND (Extent3.Color IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this

```
from _vehicle in shireyContext.Vehicles
join _statusDescription in shireyContext.StatusDescriptions
on _vehicle.Status equals _statusDescription.StatusId
join _newOptions2 in shireyContext.VehicleOption_New into VehicleNew
on _vehicle.StockNo equals _newOptions2.StockNo
where _vehicle.NewOrUsed == NewOrUsed && _vehicle.Model == Model && _newOptions2.Color != null
from _newOptions in VehicleNew
```

The two lines that are changed are:

```
 join _newOptions2 in shireyContext.VehicleOption_New into VehicleNew
```

and

```
from _newOptions in VehicleNew
```

Comment: My bad! Had a typo. Notice I join newOptions2 and then select from newOptions. The last from should not be there. Thanks for your suggestion